# sails js Error: Handshake inactivity timeout

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sails.js

I am saving quite some data into the database and I kept on getting this error

```
Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
at Handshake.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:164:17)
code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
fatal: true,
timeout: 10000 }
```

I have looked through posts and quite few places mentioned increase the connection limit but when I look into the V1 sailsjs about connection limit I do not see much.  I see posts that's like 3-4 years ago talking about a file `config/connection.js` which doesn't even exist.

But I still tried adding in the config inside `config/datastore.js` to set the pool into false.
So I have in datastore of

```
  default: {

    /***************************************************************************
    *                                                                          *
    * Want to use a different database during development?                     *
    *                                                                          *
    * 1. Choose an adapter:                                                    *
    *    https://sailsjs.com/plugins/databases                                 *
    *                                                                          *
    * 2. Install it as a dependency of your Sails app.                         *
    *    (For example:  npm install sails-mysql --save)                        *
    *                                                                          *
    * 3. Then pass it in, along with a connection URL.                         *
    *    (See https://sailsjs.com/config/datastores for help.)                 *
    *                                                                          *
    ***************************************************************************/
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    url: 'mysql://user:pass@ip:port/db_name',
    pool: false,
  },
```

But I still get the error though.
Does anyone have idea what I should do about this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: make sure your MySQL server is running and you have db_name defined as a database in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a connection issue. Check it out to grant the connection is fine using some MySQL client like [MySQL WorkBench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).